# high load average and cpu usage

Tags: php-fpm, cpu-usage, load-average

I am experiencing high CPU usage here is the stats i got from server, the consumption after every restart in 15 minutes go upto 100%, what could go wrong?

I have a site in laravel  installed on the server which does not have much traffic(+- 500 users), here is the stats that i got from using top command in server.

```
top - 19:23:15 up 1 day, 10:55,  1 user,  load average: 207.49, 204.19, 190.39
Tasks: 1303 total, 143 running, 1144 sleeping,  16 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 81.4%us,  7.2%sy,  0.0%ni,  8.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.4%si,  2.6%st
Mem:  33012284k total, 23683980k used,  9328304k free,   399100k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  5473208k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                       
 7302 nginx     20   0  445m  23m 6392 R  6.9  0.1   0:06.87 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7538 nginx     20   0  450m  27m 6412 D  6.9  0.1   0:07.86 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7169 nginx     20   0  444m  22m 6580 S  6.4  0.1   0:07.30 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7138 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 6008 S  5.9  0.1   0:06.84 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7185 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 5984 R  5.4  0.1   0:06.67 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7229 nginx     20   0  443m  22m 6376 R  5.4  0.1   0:06.70 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7462 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 6340 R  5.4  0.1   0:07.06 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7474 nginx     20   0  448m  25m 6464 R  5.4  0.1   0:06.93 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7632 nginx     20   0  447m  25m 6664 R  5.4  0.1   0:06.81 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7772 nginx     20   0  447m  24m 6208 R  5.4  0.1   0:06.38 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7921 nginx     20   0  446m  24m 6372 R  5.4  0.1   0:04.36 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 8187 nginx     20   0  440m  15m 3612 R  5.4  0.0   0:00.12 php-fpm                                                                                                       
   55 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  4.9  0.0  43:25.75 events/4                                                                                                      
 7119 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 6320 S  4.9  0.1   0:07.17 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7137 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 6360 S  4.9  0.1   0:07.35 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7143 nginx     20   0  446m  24m 6380 R  4.9  0.1   0:07.22 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7215 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 6296 R  4.9  0.1   0:06.40 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7296 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 5932 S  4.9  0.1   0:07.16 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7388 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 6336 R  4.9  0.1   0:07.48 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7411 nginx     20   0  446m  24m 6436 R  4.9  0.1   0:06.77 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7576 nginx     20   0  447m  24m 6232 S  4.9  0.1   0:07.31 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7662 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 6412 R  4.9  0.1   0:06.47 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7838 nginx     20   0  445m  23m 6416 D  4.9  0.1   0:05.86 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7887 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 6352 D  4.9  0.1   0:05.95 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7896 nginx     20   0  446m  24m 6164 R  4.9  0.1   0:05.24 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7941 nginx     20   0  447m  25m 6252 D  4.9  0.1   0:04.47 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 8049 nginx     20   0  443m  20m 4800 R  4.9  0.1   0:06.69 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 8163 nginx     20   0  440m  17m 5740 R  4.9  0.1   0:00.75 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 8167 nginx     20   0  447m  23m 4396 R  4.9  0.1   0:00.96 php-fpm                                                                                                       
   61 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  4.5  0.0  44:40.33 events/10                                                                                                     
 7059 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 6276 R  4.5  0.1   0:06.66 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7125 nginx     20   0  446m  24m 6396 S  4.5  0.1   0:07.55 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7205 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 6400 S  4.5  0.1   0:06.86 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7279 nginx     20   0  448m  25m 6408 S  4.5  0.1   0:06.99 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7514 nginx     20   0  443m  21m 6412 R  4.5  0.1   0:06.83 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7546 nginx     20   0  447m  25m 6548 R  4.5  0.1   0:06.88 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7571 nginx     20   0  448m  26m 6320 R  4.5  0.1   0:07.16 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7574 nginx     20   0  444m  22m 6648 R  4.5  0.1   0:06.37 php-fpm                                                                                                       
 7583 nginx     20   0  446m  24m 6328 S  4.5  0.1   0:06.87 php-fpm
```

Comment: It would help to provide the nginx and php configuration, plus any relevant log entries.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some php code is running too slow to keep up with the load.  It also appears that far too many php-fpm processes are being spawned.

Look at the configuration for `pm.max_children`.  Try setting it to 5 or 10 and monitoring CPU usage.  Once you know the CPU usage you may be able to calculate a new value by dividing 80 by the average CPU percentage.  That may be a good starting point.